# Does Google NaCl support exceptions with a C++ 11 compiler?

Tags: c++, c++11, google-nativeclient

Google NaCL comes with at least two C++ compilers: a very old gcc version, and a very recent clang version. The gcc version does not support C++ 11, so I would rather not use it. The very new clang compiler generates intermediate code, and then either is compiled in the browser, or ones compiles it to native. I tried the first approach: having Chrome compile it in the browser. The problem: exceptions didn't work, and I need them. I checked [this](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/issues/detail?id=3377), but I really can't understand the fine print of this ticket. That leaves the second approach: compile the code to native before deploying... question: would I be able to use exceptions then? Or should I surrender any hope?

(... After Go and this, I'm under the impression that Google engineers really hate exceptions...)

Comment: "I'm under the impression that Google engineers really hate exceptions..." [you're not wrong...](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Exceptions#Exceptions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The essence of the ticket you link to is that

- you can't use C++ exceptions in PNaCl, that is, you can't use C++ exceptions if you plan to deploy as a `.pexe` file (LLVM bitcode), but
- you can use C++ exceptions with the Clang-based toolchain if you provide the flag `--pnacl-allow-exceptions` (to *both* pnacl-clang and pnacl-translate) and compile and translate all the way to a set of `.nexe` binaries before deployment.

In C++, as well as in pretty much any other language, exceptions should be used sparingly, and as you can see above some style guides suggest not using them at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't get this option to work: at translation time (now, out of the browser) I get undefined references to _Unwind... any idea of how to handle these?

Comment: You need to pass --pnacl-allow-exceptions to pnacl-translate as well as to pnacl-clang.

Answer (score 7):

In the latest versions of the PNaCl toolchain, you can enable C++ exception handling by passing the option `--pnacl-exceptions=sjlj` at link time.  The resulting pexe will work in any version of Chrome that supports PNaCl (Chrome 31 onwards).

This option converts try/catch blocks to using setjmp() internally.  The performance might not be great.  We plan on adding ABI-stable support for zero-cost exception handling later to improve the performance.

This option should eventually be available in the NaCl SDK for Chrome 33.  Until then, it's available in Canary versions of the NaCl SDK.

Comment: It's getting better! Good to know!

Answer (score 4):

- You can use C++ exceptions with the PNaCl toolchain if you plan to deploy a .nexe.

  You'll need to pass `--pnacl-allow-exceptions` to pnacl-clang when linking the .pexe and to pnacl-translate when translating the .pexe to a .nexe.

  If you don't pass this option to pnacl-translate, you'll get errors about `_Unwind_*` symbols being unresolved.  If you don't pass this option when linking the .pexe, throwing an exception will cause the program to exit.
- C++ exceptions won't be supported when the .pexe is translated by the browser in the first release of PNaCl.  As above, throwing an exception will cause the program to exit.  But a later release will support C++ exceptions.